# Needs to open find my iPhone or login to iCloud.com from Application

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit, icloud-api

I'm working on an application that customer needs to show location of other devices in app.

I have a meeting with my customer and he is open in solution of doing that. So I checked my solution such as open find my iPhone application or open icloud web site.
I tried to open find my iPhone application from my application to easy to use action, but I did not find any way to do that.

Then I tried to open icloud.com in a web view, then I found this web site is not responsive and It does not show login page and other actions!!!

I have another guess to do, using could api to get this info, but Im not sure it is possible!

Could any one help me about this action? Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are complete websites collecting iPhone URL schemes, for example [this one](http://handleopenurl.com). But for "Find my iPhone" there is nothing, so I am afraid the answer will be "you can't". (Or nobody has added the scheme to handleopenurl.com)

Comment: Tnx, In this site i found another app like find my iphone; I hope the find friends app meets my customer needs :)